# porting image rotations to android

Tags: java, android, canvas, porting, affinetransform

I wanted to write a little game in Android, since I have good Java experiancas I wrote it first in Java. Now I want to port the game, but unfortunately Android library does not support "AffineTransform" or "Graphics2d".
I know that the rotation can be done by using canvas, but I did not manage to display the images yet.
The problem that I have is that the onDraw method is never called. Below is an example code that I used in Java and want to port to Android.

```
public void drawEdge(Edge edge, Graphics g){
.... computation Stuff
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
AffineTransform att = new AffineTransform();
att.translate(posX,posY);
att.rotate(rotAngle);
g2d.drawImage(lineImage, att, null);
}
```

So in Android I tried this:

```
public void drawEdge(Edge edge, Graphics g){
.... computation Stuff
Paint mPaint = new Paint();
canvas.drawLine(200, 200, 400, 400, mPaint); // Just a simple line not the edge yet
}
```

But this does not work. I also tried to create the onDraw method, but it seems to be never called. Furthermore I am not able to load the limeImage as a bitmap. I used :

```
Assets.lineBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("LineImage.png");
```

and get the massege: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException. But using:

```
Assets.lineImage = g.newImage("Line_height6.png", ImageFormat.RGB565);
```

works just fine.

I know there are a lot of tutorials considering the usage of canvas but I still can't figure out what is wrong with the code, so if any one has any clue for me, I would really appreciate it.

Best Sergej

Answer (score 0):

All right I managed to draw the line in the above code, the problem was that I the itmap file was not improter: solved with

```
    FileIO fileIO = game.getFileIO();
    InputStream in = null;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    try {
        in = fileIO.readAsset("Line_height6.png");
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } 
    catch(IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't load texture '" + "Line_height6.png", e);}
```

So what I do now is that I use the canvas created at the beginning of the game. Then I can draw the line. So far so good. But if I want to rotate the bitmap, then the background rotates too. My attempt of the solution was to create a new canvas using the bitmap:

```
Bitmap bmp = lineBitmap;
Bitmap mutableBitmap = bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
Canvas newcanvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
newcanvas.rotate((float) theta);
newcanvas.drawBitmap(mutableBitmap, matrix, paint2);
```

But I get no new picture or an error at all now. The background is there, as well as some othere images I draw on the original canvas but I can not display the rotates bitmap.
Any suggestions?